# Populate an email with data from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, email

I have an Excel spreadsheet of contacts. I want to set a drop-down list that sends an email to the specific person I choose and returns the contact info in the body of the email.

I don't know how to get the email to auto-populate and right now, the email that pops up has "true" in the body for the contact info rather than returning the text value in the cell.

```
Sub DropDown7_Change()

    Dim answer As String

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to assign this lead?", _
        vbYesNo, "Send Email")
    '    Above code informs the user that an automated email will be sent

    'Code uses the users answer to either carryout the generated email process or to not save the changes.
    If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
    If Cancel = True Then Exit Sub

    If answer = vbYes Then  
        'Connects to outlook and retrieves information needed to create and send the email.
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        'Contains the email address of the person receiving the email.
        newmsg.Subject = "Lead Assigned to You" 'Sets the automated subject line to the email
        newmsg.Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & _
            "You have been assigned a lead. Please follow up with the contact" & vbNewLine & _
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("K5").Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Range("K5").Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("K5").Select

        'Above code has the body of the automated email
        newmsg.Display
    End If

End Sub ' End of function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the values that are `Offset` to `Range("K5")` , then you need to use the `Offset` with `.Value` , like this `Range("K5").Offset(0, 3).Value` , this will get the value 3 columns to the right of Cell "K5".

The code below, will add the values from 3 cells with Columns offset to cell "K5" to you email body:

```
Sub DropDown7_Change()

    Dim answer As String

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to assign this lead?", _
        vbYesNo, "Send Email")
    '    Above code informs the user that an automated email will be sent

    'Code uses the users answer to either carryout the generated email process or to not save the changes.
    If answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If answer = vbYes Then

            'Connects to outlook and retrieves information needed to create and send the email.
            Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            'Contains the email address of the person receiving the email.
            newmsg.Subject = "Lead Assigned to You" 'Sets the automated subject line to the email
            newmsg.body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & _
                "You have been assigned a lead. Please follow up with the contact" & vbNewLine & _
                Range("K5").Offset(0, 3).Value & vbNewLine & _
                Range("K5").Offset(0, 6).Value & vbNewLine & _
                Range("K5").Offset(0, 7).Value & vbNewLine                    

            'Above code has the body of the automated email
            newmsg.Display
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```